# Visual Studio Git sync to svn

Tags: git, visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2015

In our company we are using svn for as source control, however for local repository I'm using git. When I created new solution I opted in for VS2015 creating git repo for me and it is working ok. I am wondering if there is an easy way to setup link between svn and git in visual studio so I can sync my project with svn inside a visual studio instead of running svn commands or using something like tortoiseSvn?

Answer (score 0):

From VS, no. Have a look at git-svn.

Or if you want to switch to svn, there is plugins. I remember ankhsvn.

Comment: I would like to keep git for local repositories. Is there a way to initialize svn into local git via git-svn? I found some guides but it seems not be my case. I want just to link existing remote svn repo to my local git.

Comment: I don't know. I just know that it's the way to go. But I think that you have to clone with git-svn and then go with it. But with some (advanced) git knowledge you could use the actual git folder as a remote, import your history and retrieve your changes/commits.